# Bootstrap Input Group issues on width of Input Type Date

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have been developing an application. After using the assets of bootstrap, i found a strange issue that i cant resolve. I know very much about CSS but this is something very tricky. I am not able to resolve it being a front-end developer.

I have simply added input type date in an bootstrap input group. But after making it more smaller and smaller, it overflows outside the div. I have tried everything to fix it both i had no success at all. I want it work like the simple input group do.

For illustration, i have added a red color at background. to show the difference between date and text inputs.

Here is the code:

```css
.color { background: red; padding-top:20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
         <div class="color">
            <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="input-group"> 
               <span class="input-group-addon">Date</span>
               <input class="form-control " placeholder="From" type="date">
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="input-group"> 
               <span class="input-group-addon">Text</span>
               <input class="form-control " placeholder="From" type="text">
            </div>
            </div>
            
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Do i miss something?

Thanks

Comment: You should know that input group has display table, table level element stop resizing after particular width which depends on the content inside the display table child elements. you have to remove the display table after particular width where you faces the issue or change from display table to display block using a media query.

Comment: It just need more space to show both field and label, try col-xs-5

Comment: hi @Chilll007, thanks for reply, i agree with you, but what happens when i use type=date in type=text it looks perfect but when i use type=date it distorts.. why reason for that? i have also tried all possible idea for arranging it but no success at all.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this so we can check what is happening.

Comment: hi @AwsmeSandy, thanks for reply, actually at some instances the input group could be small also, but at some width it overflows.. i want to vanish that overflows. Just like type=text..

Comment: @Chilll007 i have check in question..

Comment: it is a bug with input type date and display table-cell https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346051

Comment: @Chilll007 i know its a bug but how to fix it, there must be any tricky or alternative to get the desired result.

Comment: you can use the bootstrap datetimepicker which uses the input type text to generate date time picker which will solve your issue for now. https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: @Chilll007 Actually i want to fix it by HTML or CSS only, no jquery, no plugin. Just CSS or HTML..

Comment: do one thing try to assign min-width:100% and give width 50px to your date input and see what happens.

Comment: @Chilll007 yeah it looks fine now... Thank you for the quick fix...

Comment: i will update it as answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `min-width: 100%;` and `width: 50px;` it will solve the issue.